# Multiplication as repeated addition based on another function?

Tags: python, algorithm

how am I suppose to do the multiplication based on repeated additions, but calling the add() function that I made, into the multiply function? I thought of using the add() function in the "for" loop but I just can't think of how I would actually do it.

Edit: My question is basically how can I use the "add()" function into the multiply() function in a for loop to make a multiplication operation based on repeated additions?

***SOURCE CODE:***

```
def add (num1,num2):
    return num1 + num2

def subtract (num1,num2):
    return num1 - num2

def multiply(num1,num2):

    sum_of_num = 0
    for i in range(0,num2,1):
        sum_of_num += num1
    return sum_of_num
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the `+=` with your `add` function:

```
def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

def subtract(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2

def multiply(num1, num2):
    sum_of_num = 0
    for i in range(num2):
        sum_of_num = add(sum_of_num, num1)
    return sum_of_num
```

Comment: Thanks, but can I know what you mean by for i in range(num2)? like is that starting from range 0 to num2? or what is that doing excalty and thanks.

Comment: Yes, in [`range(start, stop, step)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range), if omitted, `start` defaults to `0` and `step` to `1`.

Comment: Great that explains it and makes a lot of sense.